# Where can I find CDA MIF and RMIM

Tags: xml, hl7, cda, hl7-cda, hl7-v3

I'm evaluating this [Model-based mapping and transformation tools](http://www.openmapsw.com/downloads/downloads.htm) for mapping application data to one type of Consolidated CDA. The idea of this tool is to build a EMF class model using CDA RMIM, MIF (Model Exchange Format) and probably C-CDA Schematron. In a way it can simplify mapping by creating a simplified model and transform. I wonder if anyone had some experience with this tool and could share it with me. You can find guide and samples in the download, but what's lacking is the part related to CDA. I'm particularly interested in how to build the EMF model, but there's only description (hard to follow) but no example. I also have been searching for info on CDA RMIM and MIF, there're plenty info on describing what they are. But I just couldn't find any sample files. Based on my reading, MIF seems particularly meaningful for tooling. I also wonder if there's any existing tool that would deal with MIF file.

Answer (score 3):

1.MIF is a  customized UML format for HL7 V3 Message and Document standards artifacts .if you get any version (2012JAN,2009SEP) fullsite package of HL7 V3 standards from this download page for example[1]:http://www.hl7.org/v3ballotarchive/v3ballot2012may/html/welcome/downloads.when you open this full site zip file ,you will find the mif files in the directory "V3BALLot\html\processable\MIF1-Lite" then you can find the file"POCD_MT000040UV.mif" for the CDA R2.

2.If you want the RMIM for CDA R2,you can  goole the key word "CDA_R2_NormativeWebEdition2005" or get from this site:http://synoptic-report.googlecode.com/svn/tags/old%20trunk/doc/CDA_R2_NormativeWebEdition2005/,then you can browse the index page. or just search the file "L-POCD_RM000040.gif"

3.there is not any off the shelf tools to deal with the MIF.If you are in US,I strongly recommend the tools MDHT ,for else you can try Marc-HI framework(everest.marc-hi.ca).

Comment: CDA MIF is not normative. That's why it can be found in the v3 ballot package, but not in the normative edition. Just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used the tool in a while but the CDA RMIM and MIF should be available on the hl7 site as part of the download package for the specification  MDHT has a series of UML capturing the constraints and corresponding ecore models
Here is a link to the page

https://www.projects.openhealthtools.org/sf/projects/mdht/

Answer (score 0):

OHT Model Driven Health Tools is good. There is also a new initiative called [art-decor](http://art-decor.org/art-decor/decor-templates--ad1bbr-) that is quite interesting. It's a template registry of sorts for CDA templates. [Lantana Group](https://www.lantanagroup.com) also has a tool called [Trifolia Workbench](https://www.lantanagroup.com/newsroom/press-releases/trifolia-workbench-hl7-web-edition/). My suggestion would be not to re-invent the wheel and look and see what is already out there.